# How do I center a 1700px div so that no horizontal scrollbars appear?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site with a 1700px wide JS slideshow at the top. When I publish the page, I get horizontal scrollbars since my monitor is on a 1024px resolution. How do I get the site to be centered in the browser with no horizontal scrollbars - and whatever is superfluous on either side simply isn't visible to the user?
Help GREATLY appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: if you design a 1700px when using a 1024px resolution, the sides will obviously not be visible to the user, especially when you remove the scrollbars. That's kind of logic, don't you think?

Comment: @krike: The question is how to **remove** the scrollbars.

Comment: @Matthew: yes I know that's why I commented instead of answering. And I only answered his second question (found in the description of his question) -> "and whatever is superfluous on either side simply isn't visible to the user?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

But this will also stop people scrolling if their monitor is smaller than the main width of your site.

The real solution is to simply not have it be 1700px wide all the time. Something like the following may help, but it depends on your HTML and how your slideshow is implemented.

```
#slideshow { width: 100%; max-width: 1700px; }
```

<strike>I haven't tested this, but you may be able to get away with putting the above CSS on a container element, something like this:</strike>

```
#slideshow-container { width: 100%; max-width: 1700px; }
#slideshow { width: 1700px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

You can do this pretty easily. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NDkaX/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I managed to get it working, i also used overflow-x: hidden but I applied it to the html tag. I removed the width declaration from my #slideshow_wrapper div but still it wasn't working, I couldn't figure what was going on until I remembered that the stylesheet belonging to the JS that makes the slideshow work also declares the width. There I just set width: auto and voila! It works yay!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As you know the size of the div, use that:

```
div.slideshow {
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:50%;
  margin-left:-850px; /* 1700/2 */
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer! I had actually found a way to make it work - but I find your solution interesting. Will setting a margin-left: -850px; not screw it up for different screen resolutions? If it is setting the margin, what happens if someone is on a 1024px? I think I will go test it :D thanks!